# Aligning the equations and equation numbers correctly

Tags: equations, minipage

I have the following code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}{16cm}
Maximization:\\
\begin{minipage}{7.6cm}
\begin{align}
&\sup_{{g_0}\in\mathcal{G}_0} P_F(\delta,g_0)\nonumber\\
&\mbox{s.t.} \quad  g_0>0 , \Upsilon(g_0)=\int_{\mathbb{R}}g_0\mbox{d}\mu=1,\nonumber
\end{align}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{7.6cm}
\begin{align}\label{equation311}
&\sup_{{g_1}\in\mathcal{G}_1} P_M(\delta,g_1)\nonumber\\
&\mbox{s.t.} \quad  g_1>0, \Upsilon(g_1)=\int_{\mathbb{R}}g_1\mbox{d}\mu=1.\nonumber
\end{align}
\end{minipage}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{16cm}
Minimization:\\
\begin{equation}
\min_{\delta\in\Delta} P_E(\delta,\hat{g}_0,\hat{g}_1)
\end{equation}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

and I use

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside,a4paper]
```

Here is the output[image]

Problems are as follows:

The equation number is outside the text and the formulas are also almost overlapping with the text, including '**Maximization:**'. I want a normal vertical space of say equation environment in all cases. I don't want to arrange the vspaces and hspaces by hand because it won't be accurate, especially for the equation number which must be aligned with all other equation numbers in the text.

One more thing: Although I use align environment $\sup$ and "s.t." are als not well aligned, as it can be seen in the figure.

What is the best way of solving this problem?

Comment: Well, 16cm is about 455pt, but `\documentclass[12pt,twoside,a4paper]` sets `\textwidth` to 390pt, so it's no wonder things overrun the margin. It's usually better to use fractions of `\textwidth` for minipages. Beyond that, it's hard to see exactly what you want; perhaps you could upload a picture to illustrate this.

Comment: @IanThompson \begin{minipage}{390pt} couldnt align. What I want is as follows: If I am able to used just one align environment or just one equation environment, then everything is fine. Because there is enough vspace and equations are perfectly alligned. BUT; I am not able to do it with a single align or even with a few align. Therefore I use minipage and it creates me unwanted problems as shown with the image.

Comment: @SeyhmusGüngören Ian Thompson suggested you use `\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}`. And it works quite fine if then you make the two sub-level minipages `\begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth}`.

Comment: @ManuelWeinkauf Ok. I had understood it wrong. Now I did it and it works fine. Still vspaces are problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Rather than fight with `minipage` environments, you could try turning it round like this:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
    \begin{aligned}
        \text{Maximization:}\quad &
        \begin{aligned}
            &\sup_{g_0\in\mathcal{G}_0} P_F(\delta,g_0) 
             \quad \text{s.t. $g_0>0$, $\Upsilon(g_0)=\int_{\mathbb{R}}g_0\,\mathrm{d}\mu=1$}\\
            &\sup_{g_1\in\mathcal{G}_1} P_M(\delta,g_1) 
             \quad \text{s.t. $g_1>0$, $\Upsilon(g_1)=\int_{\mathbb{R}}g_1\,\mathrm{d}\mu=1$}
        \end{aligned}
        \\[12pt]
        \text{Minimization:}\quad &\min_{\delta\in\Delta} P_E(\delta,\hat{g}_0,\hat{g}_1)
    \end{aligned}
\end{equation}


\end{document}
```

Comment: I must confess that is seems really nice. Btw, why min is not perfectly aligned with sups?  I also think that maximization could better be aligned with the first sup rather than being in the middle. I am trying now.

Comment: because the subscripts stick out a bit...

Comment: One more thing. Is it possible to take the equation number to bottom. Namely to the same line with "minimization"?

Comment: @SeyhmusGüngören Just use `\begin{aligned}[b]`.

Comment: @Manuel I used it and in all cases I solved my problem with the equation number but in neither cases (using [b] for the inner, outer and both aligneds) I was able to get Maximization aligned with the first "sup"

Comment: @SeyhmusGüngören It was meant to solve the issue with the number using `[b]` in the outer aligned. The other problem, as Thruston said, is because of the subscripts, if you load `mathtools` package instead of `amsmath` you can use `\sup_{\mathclap{g_0\in\mathcal{G}_0}}` so that they take no space and you end with `\sup` and `\inf` aligned.

Comment: @Manuel you are again right. I did it but why instead of? I loaded both packages and used \mathclap as you said and they are now aligned. How about Maximization? can I take it up? [b] only can take the equation number down.

Comment: @SeyhmusGüngören Instead because, citing barbara beeton, “`mathtools` loads `amsmath`, so it's not necessary to explicitly load both”. In any case the `[b]` in the *outer* one puts the number down; a `[t]` in the *inner* one puts `Maximization:` in the top line, if I understand correctly.

Comment: @Manuel great. Exactly, this was what I meant. I thought that you meant "instead" because they would crash or would not work jointly. Now I understood after you comment that mathtool would imply amsmath. Thx.

Answer (score 4):

this should give exactly the result requested, grouping lines with a combination of the
multi-line display environments provided by `amsmath`.  `mathtools` is loaded instead
of `amsmath` to be able to use `\shortintertext`; `mathtools` loads `amsmath`, so it's
not necessary to explicitly load both.

there is an added `\,` before the `\text{s.t.}` to account for the fact that a thin space
is automatically added before an operator (`\sup`), and it was requested that these line up.
`\text` is generally preferable to `\mbox`, as it will choose the correct size.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\numberwithin{equation}{section}

\begin{document}
\setcounter{section}{3}
\setcounter{equation}{22}
\noindent
XXXXX
\begin{gather}
\shortintertext{Maximization:}
\begin{alignedat}{5}
&\sup_{{g_0}\in\mathcal{G}_0} && P_F(\delta,g_0)
 &&\sup_{{g_1}\in\mathcal{G}_1} && P_M(\delta,g_1) \\
\qquad&\,\text{s.t.}  && g_0>0 , \Upsilon(g_0)=\int_{\mathbb{R}}g_0\mbox{d}\mu=1,\qquad
 && \,\text{s.t.} && g_1>0, \Upsilon(g_1)=\int_{\mathbb{R}}g_1\mbox{d}\mu=1.
 \nonumber
\end{alignedat}\\
\shortintertext{Minimization:}
\min_{\delta\in\Delta} P_E(\delta,\hat{g}_0,\hat{g}_1)
\label{equation311}
\end{gather}
XXXXX
\end{document}
```

[image: output of example code]

Comment: `\,` seems unnecessary. TeX adds a thin space in front of `\sup` only in certain cases, if it's the “first item in the list” the space is not added (I hope I'm not using words that have certain important meaning here).

Comment: @Manuel -- thanks for the observation.  i added the `\.` because when i tested this, the "s.t." was visibly aligned to the left of the "sup" expression.  i hesitate to remove it for that reason.

Comment: In fact, here it's added since you have `&` before it (which adds an invisible `\mathord{}` I think). So I got it wrong. In any case, part of the space is because of the subscript, so `\mathclap{..}` would be handy.

Comment: @Manuel -- i began each row with `&` expressly because the op requested alignment.  your conjecture is correct.  in this particular case, `\clap` would probably work, but if the lower limit on "sup" were wider, or whatever follows it had a descender, it might not.  if one is really fussy, then more experimentation along those lines would be in order.

Comment: thx for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

This does not solve the problem, but at least it provides a real minimal example for others to try, including all necessary packages. Next time, this is **your job** (this is not your first question, so more effort could be expected). Additionally, if you want to solve the problem with misaligned equation numbers, you hardly should deactivate them in your code, should you?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}{16cm}
Maximization:\\
\begin{minipage}{7.6cm}
\begin{align}
&\sup_{{g_0}\in\mathcal{G}_0} P_F(\delta,g_0)\\
&\mbox{s.t.} \quad  g_0>0 , \Upsilon(g_0)=\int_{\mathbb{R}}g_0\mbox{d}\mu=1,
\end{align}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{7.6cm}
\begin{align}\label{equation311}
&\sup_{{g_1}\in\mathcal{G}_1} P_M(\delta,g_1)\\
&\mbox{s.t.} \quad  g_1>0, \Upsilon(g_1)=\int_{\mathbb{R}}g_1\mbox{d}\mu=1,
\end{align}
\end{minipage}
\end{minipage}

\begin{minipage}{16cm}
Minimization:\\
\begin{equation}
\min_{\delta\in\Delta} P_E(\delta,\hat{g}_0,\hat{g}_1)
\end{equation}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I dont have the intension to deactivate them. Try to compile your answer. It is very problematic. I am editing the question in a minute.